Next.js server actions not returning
I have a small next.js project using server actions, calling a server action from a client component. I have had no other issues with any other server actions (about 5 of them). The response populates the dropdown fine when I load the page for the first time, but then once I refresh the page the response fails and after that I have to go to a different page then back to load the data.
Here is my component:
  "use client";
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
  import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
  import { getGenuses } from '@/server/plants';

  const FilterBar: React.FC = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();

  const initialGenus = searchParams.get('genus') || 'All';
  const initialMinPrice = searchParams.get('minPrice') || '';
  const initialMaxPrice = searchParams.get('maxPrice') || '';

  const [genus, setGenus] = useState(initialGenus);
  const [minPrice, setMinPrice] = useState(initialMinPrice);
  const [maxPrice, setMaxPrice] = useState(initialMaxPrice);
  const [genuses, setGenuses] = useState<string[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchGenuses() {
      console.log("Fetching genuses...");
      try {
        console.log("Genus fetch attemt")
        const response = await getGenuses();
        console.log("Genuses fetched:", response);  
        if (response.genuses) {
          console.log("Updating state with genuses:", response.genuses);
          setGenuses(['All', ...response.genuses]);
        } else {
          console.error("No genuses in response", response);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to fetch genuses:", error);
      }
    }
    
    
    fetchGenuses();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams.toString());
    if (genus !== 'All') {
      params.set('genus', genus);
    } else {
      params.delete('genus');
    }
    if (minPrice) {
      params.set('minPrice', minPrice);
    } else {
      params.delete('minPrice');
    }
    if (maxPrice) {
      params.set('maxPrice', maxPrice);
    } else {
      params.delete('maxPrice');
    }
    router.push(`/shop?${params.toString()}`);
  }, [genus, minPrice, maxPrice]);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col space-y-4 my-8 px-4">
      <div>
        <label className="block mb-2">Genus:</label>
        <select
          value={genus}
          onChange={(e) => setGenus(e.target.value)}
          className="input input-bordered w-full h-8"
        >
          {genuses.map((g) => (
            <option key={g} value={g}>{g}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label className="block mb-2">Price Range:</label>
        <div className="flex space-x-2">
          <input
            type="number"
            value={minPrice}
            onChange={(e) => setMinPrice(e.target.value)}
            className="input input-bordered w-full h-8"
            placeholder="Min"
          />
          <input
            type="number"
            value={maxPrice}
            onChange={(e) => setMaxPrice(e.target.value)}
            className="input input-bordered w-full h-8"
            placeholder="Max"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  };

  export default FilterBar;

And here is my server action:
  export async function getGenuses() {
  console.log("Server: Calling getGenuses");
  try {
    const genuses = await prisma.plant.findMany({
      distinct: ['genus'],
      select: { genus: true },
    });
    console.log("Server: Genuses fetched", genuses);
    const genusNames = genuses.map(plant => plant.genus).sort();
    console.log({ genuses })
    return { genuses: genusNames };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("ERR")
    console.error("Server: Error fetching genuses:", error);
    return { error: 'Failed to fetch genuses' };
  }
  }

And here are the client logs:
Fetching genuses...
filterBar.tsx:23 Genus fetch attemt
filterBar.tsx:21 Fetching genuses...
filterBar.tsx:23 Genus fetch attemt

And the server logs:
Server: Calling getGenuses
Server: Genuses fetched [
  { genus: 'Musa' },
  { genus: 'Nephrolepis' },
  { genus: 'Monstera' },
  { genus: 'Sarracenia' },
  { genus: 'Dionaea' },
  { genus: 'Sansevieria' },
  { genus: 'Zamioculcas' },
  { genus: 'Spathiphyllum' },
  { genus: 'Chlorophytum ' }
]
{
  genuses: [
    { genus: 'Musa' },
    { genus: 'Nephrolepis' },
    { genus: 'Monstera' },
    { genus: 'Sarracenia' },
    { genus: 'Dionaea' },
    { genus: 'Sansevieria' },
    { genus: 'Zamioculcas' },
    { genus: 'Spathiphyllum' },
    { genus: 'Chlorophytum ' }
  ]
}
 POST /shop?sort=scientificName&order=asc 200 in 55ms
Plants query: {}
 POST /shop?sort=scientificName&order=asc 200 in 38ms

I really don't understand, everything logs up to the point at which the response comes back then nothing, no errors.
Thanks
Lots of logging, I have made a very simple server action that returns just a number but still no response on the client side.
